# Restricting content to just one category

Tags: php, wordpress, operators

I'm trying to restrict content to posts only from one category. In my loop.php I'm using the following code but with errors.

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() && cat=='1'); { ?>
```

Can someone please help

EDIT:

I'm trying to make use of else if statement in order to show excerpt if cat=1 and ignore rule if cat=161 or 158. here's the code but I get a TELSEIF error

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() && $cat== '1') { ?>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                <div class="restrict">
                Please Login/Register to read this article!
                </div>
                <?php } elseif (is_user_logged_in() && $cat== '158') { ?>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
                <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a PHP guy, but I think you must remove semicolon from the end of the line. Also, what is this `cat`, I think that this is somekind of a variable. If it is, then dollar sign is needed.

```
<?php if (is_user_logged_in() && $cat == '1') { ?>
```

**EDIT:**

```
<?php if (is_user_logged_in() && $cat == '1') { ?> 
<?php the_content(); ?> 
<?php } else { ?> 
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Looking at your code you posted on the comment, you also missing ending brackets.

Comment: Thank you. This did get rid of the error. But the problem still exists. Here is my actual code:

`<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() && cat=='1') { ?>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>`

What i'm trying to do is, to display excerpt only if category is 1, but if other category (ex 2 or 3) ignore the logic..

Comment: cat is the wordpress category. I tried with $cat but still no go

Comment: The above code still shows just the post excerpt. Despite the category id being different :(

Comment: If you want to call the_excerpt() method when category id is '1', then you must reverse calling the_content() method and the_excerpt() method.

Comment: Not quite. By reversing the methods.. if user is logged in and cat =1 then it would show the excerpt and if user is not logged in then it shows the excerpt.. which is not what I wanted to do.

Comment: Your earlier comment was: "What i'm trying to do is, to display excerpt only if category is 1, but if other category (ex 2 or 3) ignore the logic.". But I think you must debug your code and look why your code is not acting like you want it.

Comment: Hmm.. i'm trying. Tried this method as well

`<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() && $cat== '1,-158,-161') { ?>`

still no go

Comment: you could also try $cat == 1 without the quotes

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
<?php if (is_user_logged_in() && $cat == '1') { ?>
```

try

```
<?php if (is_user_logged_in() && is_category('1')) { ?>
```

the whole piece of code should

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_category('1','158','161')){
         the_content(); 
      } else { 
         the_excerpt(); 
 ?>
         <div class="restrict">
         Please Login/Register to read this article!
         </div>
 <?php } ?>
```